# When my application execute simple script file from AIX6.1, Can't get a result. Refer to stderr. How to check it properly?

Tags: aix

I have a problem.

I'd like to execute command by script file from my application on `AIX6`.1

My test environment is like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y3Nv.png)

```
"test.sh" includes "oslevel -s" command.
```

My App can run oslevel command include other options except only "oslevel -s".

> when My App execute "test.sh", get a error like this
>   "/usr/bin/oslevel[49]: test: argument expected"

So, I open oslevel file & find 49 line. But, I don't know how to fix it.

Anybody help this issue? thank you for reading.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgOzb.png)

Comment: Line 49 doesn't seem to have any `test` or `[` commands in it. Have you ever manually edited this 
 `/usr/bin/oslevel file?

Comment: My best guess is that your `/tmp` is not mounted or has no empty space

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I agree with you. I also can't find test or argument in oslevel file. I never edit '/usr/bin/oslevel file'

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond when i execute "oslevel -s" on machine directly, it runs correctly. And also, tmp is mounted and space is used 43%.

Comment: A way to debug: in your script instead of `/usr/bin/oslevel -s` use `/usr/bin/ksh -xv /usr/bin/oslevel -s 2>debug.log` .

Comment: Use text, not images, and show where/how you call oslevel. You must be passing it something unexpected.